# Chrome extension to control online music?

Tags: chrome, music, youtube, spotify

I'm looking for a Google Chrome extension that would use my keyboard media keys to control my music streaming from Youtube / Spotify

I'm tired of find the tab playing music when I just want to pause the music or switch to the next track

Do you know any good extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I made my own extension to answer this problem.

It allows you to use your keyboard media hotkeys to start/pause next/previous tracks from Youtube, Youtube Music, Spotify, Tidal and Deezer

[**Check it out on the Chrome Web Store**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pohakmokiogdbhiocmacgalcmnfdbbne)

It's also open source [fork it on Github!](https://github.com/MathiasGilson/MusicControllerChromeExtension)

[image: HotKeys Chrome music control]